# Using bibtex to cite a chapter in a handbook that is part of a series

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a chapter of a book (with editors that differ from the chapter author) that is part of a series of books with different editors. It should look like:

"Rogoff, B. (1998). Cognition as a collaborative process. In D. Kuhn & R. S. Siegler (Eds.), Cognition, language, and perceptual development (Vol. 2). In W. Damon (Series Ed.), Handbook of child psychology (5th ed., pp. 679–744). New York: John Wiley & Sons."

Can anyone offer any suggestions? At the moment I'm inclined to ignore the fact that the book is part of a series but this seems like a cop out!

Many thanks!

Comment: The `@incollection` entry type would seem most likely to do the job. Please indicate which bibliography style you use. Posting the entry as you currently have it would also be useful. When there's both an editor (or group of editors) of an individual volume as well as an editor (or a group of editors) of the entire series, it's usually not necessary to mentioning the series editor(s); mentioning the editors of the specific volume would probably be considered to be good form.